# init method for custom SCNView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

I have created a custom class "CustomSCNView" that inherits from SCNView. I want to use the custom class in another view controller. So I need to create a CustomSCNView object and use it to another class to manipulate things. But how can I create a CustomSCNView object in another class.
This is not working:

```
CustomSCNView *customView = [[CustomSCNView alloc]init]; //in viewcontroller.m
```

Sorry forgot to mention I used the interface builder to drag a SCNView to the view controller and then set its class to CustomSCNView.

Comment: I have a stupid, but necessary question, did you add the import statement for CustomSCNView in the other class?

Comment: have you tried `-initWithFrame:options:`?

Comment: Yea I did. I didnt make an init method for the CustomSCNView class. I assumed that [[CustomSCNView alloc]init] would work.

Comment: So can I call that method -initWithFrame:options: without initializing it in CustomScnView.m?

Comment: the initWithFrame method is not working either.

Comment: Why are you subclassing `SCNView`? You're almost certainly going to be better off using the callbacks of `SCNSceneRendererDelegate`, implemented either in a game manager object or in a Massive View Controller.

Comment: By dragging a `SCNView` to the view controller and setting its class to `CustomSCNView` in the nib/storyboard file, you have already created an instance of `CustomSCNView`. (It will be created when the nib is loaded). Are you saying you want to also create a second instance of `CustomSCNView` programmatically and display it somewhere else?

Comment: In the CustomScnView class I have a couple of properites I want to access in the view controlller. So I nee to create a CustomScnView object to access those properties. But if I use the IBOutlet scnview from main.storyboard I cant access the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question, but I've created a sample project at https://github.com/NSGod/CustomSCNView that may do what you're looking for.

First, the storyboard has 2 `CustomSCNView`s laid out side by side in the `ViewController`'s view. Like you did, I dragged 2 `SCNView`s from the IB palette to the view and then set the custom class to be `CustomSCNView`.

Second, is the `CustomSCNView` class which is defined as follows:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>

@interface CustomSCNView : SCNView

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL allowsRotation;

@end
```

You can see, it has an `allowsRotation` property that any other object can set.

To set a default value for `allowsRotation`, other than `NO`, you can override `initWithCoder:` which is what's used when you set up the views in Interface Builder like you did:

```
#import "CustomSCNView.h"

@implementation CustomSCNView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {
        _allowsRotation = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

The ViewController then has 2 `IBOutlet`s to both `CustomSCNView`s.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>

@class CustomSCNView;

@interface ViewController : NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet CustomSCNView *sView1;
@property (weak) IBOutlet CustomSCNView *sView2;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomSCNView.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _sView1.allowsRotation = NO;
    _sView2.allowsRotation = YES;
}

@end
```

You can see that in `viewDidLoad`, you can set the `allowsRotation` property of both views to whatever you want. When you run this application, 2 instances of `CustomSCNView` are created for you automatically (via `initWithCoder:`), when the storyboard/nib files are loaded. There's no need to create another instance of a `CustomSCNView` to be able to set the properties of the 2 existing instances you already have.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was I was assigning the properties as just nonatomic, not assign as well

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNView/initWithFrame:options:) for `SCNView` it tells you:

> You can create a SceneKit view by using its `initWithFrame:options:`
>   method or by adding it to a nib file or storyboard.

So you cannot use the `init` method unless you have implemented your `[CustomSCNView init]` method to call `[super initWithFrame:options:]`.

Comment: So what i did was dragged a SCNView to the view controller and set contraints in main.storyboard. Then set the SCNView's class to CustomSCNView.

Comment: @Harshil.Chokshi There is no mention of that in your question.  I think doing that should have worked.

Comment: Sorry edited my question. For some reason the [[CustomSCNView alloc]init] does not work. Do you want me to post the classes' code?

Comment: @Harshil.Chokshi You cannot use the `[CustomSCNView alloc]init]` method, as described in my answer.

Comment: So what method do I use if I am using main.storyboard? I cannot use the initWithFrame method since I am using the storyBoard to create the SCNView, and its size depends on the size of the screen

Comment: You don't need any method.  You use an outlet to connect the view to the code and the outlet will be set when the storyboard loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to custom subclass properties from Interface Builder, mark those properties `IBInspectable` (and possibly implement `IBDesignable`). That's [documented by Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html), and [nicely summarized on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/).

In any initialization path, you must call the superclass's designated initializer. For `SCNView`, that appears to be `initWithFrame:options:` (not documented as such, but the header strongly implies it). See this [document on multiple initializers and subclassing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html).

That said, though, subclassing `SCNView` is a code smell that you might be fighting the framework and working too hard.

Comment: Yea I agree. The reason I need to do it is because I want some objects to rotate by touch and some objects not to rotate. So I one sceneview allows rotatation, while the other one doesn't.

Comment: "did not work" isn't a very helpful description. Edit your original question, show us `CustomSCNView`'s `init` and `initWithFrame:` methods, and give us precise descriptions of misbehavior and error messages.